# How to clone conda environment, which have pip packages besides of conda packages?

Tags: import, pip, export, conda, clone

**Context**

I am trying to clone my dev conda environment to a test server. In this environment besides of many conda packages I had to install some packages via `pip`. I am using miniconda.

**What I've tried:**

```
conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt
```

then

```
conda create --name myclonedenv --file spec-file.txt
```

however this is not installing the few packages what were installed via `pip` in the original conda environment.

**Question**

How can I export a current conda environment, and clone it on an other machine, if the current conda environment contains some packages installed via `pip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `conda env export` command will capture both Conda- and Pip-installed packages. The YAML can then be used with `conda env create` to recreate the environment.

Answer (score 9):

This is a much faster way to clone a conda environment containing pip installations:

`conda create --name cloned --clone original`