# Installing multiple libraries from one python environment to another

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm a novice in Python and I wanted to migrate my work from one Python Environment to another one in a different machine, so is there another way to reinstall all of those libraries that I used in my original environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, you can check the libraries (and their dependencies) and store them in a text file using this command:

```
    pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then, when you are using your other machine, or even a different python environment on the same machine, install all of the libraries using this command:

```
    pip install -r /Path to file..../requirements.txt
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: You may use "conda install --file requirements.txt" if you want to install it in a conda environment.

Comment: That helps, but is there any target for the conda install?

Comment: There is no target when using conda install, it is directly installed in the active conda environment.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by featuring the `conda export` logic instead

Comment: Don't use `conda export` if mixing PyPI packages - only `conda env export` can handle those. E.g., see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72237576/570918).